# Get only issues that are linked with Jira REST-API

Tags: perl, rest, jira, jql

Is there a way to get all issues from `project a` that are linked to any other issue with the `Jira REST-API`? I'm working with the `Perl`-module `JIRA::REST`.

```
 27 $jira->POST(
 28         '/search',
 29         undef,
 30         {
 31                 jql => "project='$from_proj'",
 32                 startAt => 0,
 33                 maxResults => 1000000,
 34                 fields => ['issuelinks', 'issuetype', 'status', 'resolution', 'key']
 35         }
 36 );
```

Is there some `JQL` or something else that I could use to get the issues, I need?

Comment: Which version of Jira (not the Perl module but the paltform) are you using?

Comment: I got nothing I'm afraid. Tried around but no success. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are scripted JQL functions: https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-IssueLinks

I believe you'll need the free [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin for that.